# Cannot borrow as mutable in loop

Tags: rust

I have the [following code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c16efbb73b72324b3c4606ef4c57d721):

```rust
pub fn read_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {
    loop {
        read_exact(buf);

        if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {
            return packet;
        }
    }
}

fn read_exact(_: &mut [u8]) {
    todo!()
}

fn to_packet<'a>(_: &'a [u8]) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    todo!()
}
```

I get the following error:

```rust
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*buf` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/lib.rs:3:9
  |
1 | pub fn read_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {
  |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
2 |     loop {
3 |         read_exact(buf);
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
4 | 
5 |         if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {
  |                                         --- immutable borrow occurs here
6 |             return packet;
  |                    ------ returning this value requires that `*buf` is borrowed for `'a`
```

I think it should work because:

1. The mutable borrow in `read_exact` completes on line 3.
2. If `to_packet` returns `Some` then the value is returned to the caller.
3. If not, the immutable borrow of `to_packet` is over at the end of the loop. So it is free to be taken mutable borrow of in the next iteration.

Can somebody please let me know why this doesn't work?

#### EDIT:

It seems like a current borrow checker limitation. I tried using Polonius in the nightly and it works fine with

```
RUSTFLAGS=-Zpolonius cargo +nightly check
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a compiler limitation atm.
You could refactor to something like:

```rust
pub fn read_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) {
    loop {
        if read_exact(buf) {
            break;
        }
    }
}


fn is_packet(a: &[u8]) -> bool {
    true
}
fn read_exact<'a>(a: &'a mut [u8]) -> bool {
    is_packet(a)
}

fn to_packet<'a>(_: &'a [u8]) -> Option<&'a [u8]> {
    todo!()
}

fn process_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) {
    read_packet(buf);
    let _packet = to_packet(buf);
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b27e0552a4929b22a58dd919db60de66)

Answer (score 1):

```rust
pub fn read_packet<'a>(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {     |
    let buf = buffer;                                          |
    loop {                                                     |
        read_exact(buf);                                       \/
        if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {              'a _
            return packet;                                     |
        }                                                      |
    }                                                          |
}                                                              
                                         
fn read_exact(_: &mut [u8]) {
    todo!()
}

fn to_packet<'b>(_from: &'b [u8]) -> Option<&'b [u8]> {
    todo!()
}
```

Compile error:

```rust
  |
1 | pub fn read_packet<'a>(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {     
  |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
4 |         read_exact(buf);                                       
  |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
5 |         if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {              
  |                                         --- immutable borrow occurs here
6 |             return packet;                                   
  |                    ------ returning this value requires that `*buf` is borrowed for `'a`
```

With Non Lexical Lifetime (NLL):

- The return statement constrains the `packet` lifetime to be `'a`.
- If `packet` is `'a`, so `buf` (to_packet) has to be also `'a`.
- `'a` is valid for the entire function. The loop makes the shared reference lifetime conflicts with the exclusive reference lifetime at the next iteration.

The conflict can be reproduced without the loop. This snippet doesn't compile for the same reason that `buff` is `'a`. And we see that the root cause is the conditional return. Again 'a has to be valid for the entire function.

```rust
pub fn read_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {
    if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {    'a _
        return packet;                           |
    }                                            |
    read_exact(buf);                             |
    return &[0];                                \/
}

fn read_exact(_: &mut [u8]) {
    todo!()
}

fn to_packet<'b>(_: &'b [u8]) -> Option<&'b [u8]> {
    todo!()
}
```

Compile error:

```rust
  |
1 | pub fn read_packet<'a>(buf: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {
  |                    -- lifetime `'a` defined here
2 |     if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {
  |                                     --- immutable borrow occurs here
3 |         return packet;
  |                ------ returning this value requires that `*buf` is borrowed for `'a`
4 |     }
5 |     read_exact(buf);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ mutable borrow occurs here
```

With NLL, the lifetime is infered like you thought it would be.

```rust
pub fn read_packet<'a>(buffer: &'a mut [u8]) -> &'a [u8] {     
    let buf = buffer;                                          
    loop {                                                     
        read_exact(buf);                                       
        if let Some(packet) = to_packet(buf) {              'x _
            return packet;                                     |
        }                                                     \/
    }                                                          
}                                                              
                                         
fn read_exact(_: &mut [u8]) {
    todo!()
}

fn to_packet<'b>(_from: &'b [u8]) -> Option<&'b [u8]> {
    todo!()
}
```