# Drop borrow in each loop iteration

Tags: rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

This is a reproducible simplification of my problem:

```rust
struct Val<'a>(&'a str);

impl Val<'_> {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&str> {
        Some(self.0)
    }
}

// Not used here, but this borrow needs to be mutable
fn test<'a>(param: &'a mut Val<'a>) -> Option<&'a str> {
    param.get()
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    let mut v = Val(&s);
    
    while let Some(x) = test(&mut v) {
        println!("{x}");
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a73aa6b3571b3f568155fa8fcd888ace)

I get:

```
   |
17 |     while let Some(x) = test(&mut v) {
   |                              ^^^^^^
   |                              |
   |                              `v` was mutably borrowed here in the previous iteration of the loop
   |                              first borrow used here, in later iteration of loop

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0499`.
```

First I tried to change the lifetime of the borrow, to indicate that it does not live as long as the original data, like this:

```rust
fn test<'a, 'b>(param: &'b mut Val<'a>) -> Option<&'a str> {
    param.get()
}
```

But then I get:

```
   |
9  | fn test<'a, 'b>(param: &'b mut Val<'a>) -> Option<&'a str> {
   |         --  -- lifetime `'b` defined here
   |         |
   |         lifetime `'a` defined here
10 |     param.get()
   |     ^^^^^^^^^^^ function was supposed to return data with lifetime `'a` but it is returning data with lifetime `'b`
   |
   = help: consider adding the following bound: `'b: 'a`
```

Adding the suggested bound brings me back to the previous error.

I checked [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73738713/rust-double-mutable-borrow-in-while-let-statement), which suggests this is a limitation of the borrow checker, so I tried changing my code to:

```rust
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    let mut v = Val(&s);
    
    loop {
        let x = test(&mut v);
        if let Some(y) = x {
            println!("{y}");
        }
    }
}
```

[playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e635dfe04e677f870175f4cb4f381683)

But I get the same first error. In my use case `test` behaves more or less like a `next` from iterator, so I can't call it two times in the same iteration.

Is there any way to:

- return data with lifetime `'a` instead of `'b` in `fn test`?
- or, with the single `'a` lifetime, make the borrow be dropped at the end of the iteration?

---

**Edit**: When translating back to my real problem, I noticed that this example does not completely represent it, and I still had issues making it work. I did some changes to the example [here](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=77b09bb8ce91e40695393ee50d445d53) with some additional changes in lifetimes to make it work. Now it works fine. In summary, the `test` function had to do some mapping on the value returned by `get`, and in that process it was returning lifetime `'b` instead of `'a`.

Comment: The return type of `get()` has the wrong lifetime. It should be `Option<&'a str>`.

Comment: Thanks, I just tried that but still get the same error. I edited the question to elide lifetimes on the `Val` impl.

Comment: Of course you also need to have two lifetimes `'a` and `'b` for `test()`, but you don't need any dependency between `'a` and `'b`.

Comment: If you apply the two fixes (using different lifetimes for `test()` and returning `Option<&'a str>` in `get()` it works.

Comment: you can't write that in the future maybe it's will compile but I think it's require polonius lifetime.

Comment: You are right! Thanks! Could you please add this as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Note that `&'a mut Foo<'a>` is always wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66253247/5397009

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inherent function `Val::get()` has the wrong lifetime in the return value. The function returns the inner value of `Val`, so the return value should have the lifetime of that inner value. Due to [lifetime elision](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/lifetime-elision.html), the signature of your implementation of `get()` is equivalent to

```
fn get<'b>(&'b self) -> Option<&'b str>;
```

In other words, `self` will always be borrowed for the entire lifetime of the returned value, which is unnecessary. The lifetime of the borrow of `self` is completely independent of the lifetime of the returned string.

You also need to decouple the two lifetimes in `test()`, as you already tried. Here's the full working code:

```
struct Val<'a>(&'a str);

impl<'a> Val<'a> {
    fn get(&self) -> Option<&'a str> {
        Some(self.0)
    }
}

fn test<'a, 'b>(param: &'b mut Val<'a>) -> Option<&'a str> {
    param.get()
}

fn main() {
    let s = String::from("hello");
    let mut v = Val(&s);

    while let Some(x) = test(&mut v) {
        println!("{x}");
    }
}
```

(I added `'b` for clarity in `test()`. You could also simply omit it and use `&mut Val<'a>` as the type of `param`, again due to lifetime elision.)

Comment: that very specific to the structure here, that case is rare, this wouldn't work for something owned by the structure.