# Custom link list pop_back implementation

Tags: rust

I'm new to rust and try to understand &mut ref variables and mutability. I started creating a simple link list with pop_back function.

```
pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
        let mut head = &mut self.head;
        while let Some(v) = head {
            if v.next.is_none() {
                break;
            }
            head = &mut v.next;
        }
        head.take().map(|node| node.data)
    }
```

but can't make it to work. error is `cannot borrow *head as mutable more than once at a time`.
How can I tell rust that I want to only change the reference in my loop not the value?
I don't want to add another tail variable to my list so without changing structure how can I make this work?

this is the struct definition

```
pub struct Node<T> {
    data: T,
    next: Option<Box<Node<T>>>
}

pub struct SimpleLinkedList<T> {
    head: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
}
```

Comment: Mandatory reading: [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)

Comment: wow really good article. but still doesn't explain this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known limitation of the borrow checker. The next-gen [Polonius](https://github.com/rust-lang/polonius) will solve this.

In the meantime, the solution (without `unsafe`) is to repeat the calculation. In your case, this means some `unwrap()`s:

```rust
pub fn pop_back(&mut self) -> Option<T> {
    let mut head = &mut self.head;
    while head.is_some() {
        if head.as_mut().unwrap().next.is_none() {
            break;
        }
        head = &mut head.as_mut().unwrap().next;
    }
    head.take().map(|node| node.data)
}
```

See also:

- [Cannot borrow as mutable in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69850238/cannot-borrow-as-mutable-in-loop)
- [Returning a reference from a HashMap or Vec causes a borrow to last beyond the scope it's in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023871/returning-a-reference-from-a-hashmap-or-vec-causes-a-borrow-to-last-beyond-the-s)

Comment: I understand that we don't mutate the head value in the loop anymore. but it was the case before too. what I don't understand is, how rust figure it out in this case? I mean in the end `as_mut` function as well takes a `&mut self` and can internally change the head value, so why rust doesn't complain in this case? and one other question when we mutate a variable twice in a row it should be fine anyway or(like a vec push)?

Comment: @danics This is pretty complicated, but the main idea is that Rust doesn't understand that when we `break` the loop we will not use `v` anymore, and thus `head` is free. When we use `as_mut().unwrap()`, now there is no `v` and the borrow happen only when we didn't break.