# Encapsulate an object that holds a reference

Tags: rust

I use a lib (that I cannot modify), which exposes something like this (schematically):

```rust
struct LibStruct<'a> {
    obj: &'a String,
}

fn build_lib_object<'a>(obj: &'a String) -> LibStruct<'a> {
    LibStruct { obj }
}
```

Don't mind the "String" type here. It is just an example. The problem is related to the fact that build_lib_object takes a reference.

I would like to build & encapsulate LibStruct into another struct in my code. Something like that:

```rust
struct MyObj {
    lib: LibStruct<'what here ?>
}
fn build_my_obj(something: &u32) -> MyObj {
    // I'd like to build my param that I must give to build_lib_obj here
    let obj = format!("something: {}", something);

   // this obviously fails, since the obj is owned by local function
    MyObj { lib: build_lib_object(&obj) }
}
```

Even by propagating the `LibStruct`'s lifetime to the outer object, I cant find any obvious solution to build the `obj` argument in `build_my_obj`.

Is there any way to do that without using unsafe?

EDIT: Here is the unsafe solution I came up with. Does it seem ok ?

```rust
struct MyObj {
    // just here to hold the boxed value
    _boxed_obj: Rc<String>,
    lib: LibStruct<'static>
}
fn build_my_obj(something: &u32) -> MyObj {
    let obj = format!("something: {}", something);
    let _boxed_obj = Rc::new(obj);
    
    // create unsafe reference to the boxed value
    // this is safe because the boxed value is never dropped
    //  until MyObj itself is dropped
    let obj: &'static String = unsafe {
        &*Rc::into_raw(Rc::clone(&_boxed_obj))
    };
    MyObj { lib: build_lib_object(&obj), _boxed_obj }
}
```

Comment: You can't. Every object that contains a lifetime bounded object must itself be lifetime bounded, otherwise it will contain a reference to invalid memory after the lifetime expires

Comment: Propagating the lifetime should work though

Comment: It would work if `obj` was constructed outside of `build_by_obj`. But that must not be the case, and I cant find a solution that works (who will own the object that is referenced ?)

Comment: Dupe w/o answer / answer in the comments: [stopping the upward propagation of 'a lifetime specifier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76397338/stopping-the-upward-propagation-of-a-lifetime-specifier)

Comment: Trivially, `LibStruct<'static>` doesn't require a generic lifetime, but obviously that requires you to actually be able to make those (or use `unsafe` which is undesirable). Otherwise, I don't think this is possible in safe code.

Comment: Ok thanks. I editted with the unsafe workaround I found. Does it make sense ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/5397009

Comment: Note that your unsafe solution is unsound because you can write `let foo: &'static String = my_obj.lib.obj; drop (my_obj);` which results in a dangling reference.

Comment: @Jmb Both the `lib` field and the `obj` field are private, so this may be acceptable. Moreover, `Rc::into_raw(Rc::clone(&_boxed_obj))` effectively leaks the object, so it actually _will_ have static lifetime. Of course it's kind of pointless to store the `Rc` in you wrapper struct then, since the object will be leaked anyway.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Are you sure ? I thought that the Rc will keep alive the object, until it is dropped (when MyObj is) ... in which case the static reference will become a dangling. Isnt it ?   (if it is not the case, that's a memory leak, and it is not OK for me)

Comment: @Olivier You create a clone of the `Rc`, then leak the clone. This will increase the reference count to 2. Dropping the other `Rc` you store in the wrapper object will reduce it to 1. It will never go back to zero, because you leaked the other reference.

Comment: You don't really need a reference-counted pointer for what you are trying to do – a simple `Box` will do. You can convert a Box into a raw pointer using `&*my_box as *const _`. You will have to add a getter for the `lib` field that borrows the wrapper object and returns `LibStruct<'a>` where `'a` is the lifetime of the self borrow.

Comment: Your solution is already implemented by [this package](https://docs.rs/yoke/latest/yoke/) ( and perhaps by other similar packages).

Comment: Just a note: [you shouldn't use `&String`. Use `&str` instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function).

Comment: Instead of rolling your own, use a self-referential crate (especially if you have many instances of this pattern), of which the only sound I know are [`ouroboros`](https://docs.rs/ouroboros) and [`yoke`](https://docs.rs/yoke). But you should also consider telling the library developers to expose owned versions of their structs